# Convert string time stamp to seconds or milliseconds in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with the entry Logs.loc[0,1])[0:18] outputs '13:51:32.006655755' and I would like to convert this to milliseconds.

How would one convert this into milliseconds. I was trying to use the following:

dt.datetime.strptime((Logs.loc[0,1])[0:18], '%H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    dt.datetime.strptime((Logs.loc[0,1])[0:18], '%H:%M:%S.%f')

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 755

Answer (score 2):

use `pd.to_timedelta` and the `total_seconds` method

```
pd.to_timedelta(Logs.loc[0,1])[0:18]).total_seconds() * 1000
```

If you wanted to convert the entire column

```
pd.to_timedelta(Logs.iloc[:, 1].str[0:18]).dt.total_seconds() * 1000
```